# How to sort array of objects by value of different keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have an array with user_id, score, time_taken and so on.

I would like to set the array-like each user score will be added to a unique array for unique users and will be sorted by his score and time_taken value.

Here is my code

```
let data = [
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 803, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-2", "course_id": 502, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 10, "time_taken": 296000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 0, "time_taken": 293000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 30, "time_taken": 287000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 504, "score": 20, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 504, "score": 10, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
]
```

I tried to reduce the array

```
data = data.reduce((c, i) => {
    c[i.user_id] = (c[i.user_id] || 0) + parseFloat(i.score)
    return c
}, {});
```

I want the result like

```
[
{user_id: "5-a-1", score: 80, time_taken: "total time taken will be count"},
{user_id: "5-a-2", score: 30, time_taken: "total time taken will be count"},
{user_id: "8-a-1", score: 10, time_taken: "total time taken will be count"},
]
```

Comment: Please post some code, i.e. what have you tried?

Comment: Also, remember to actually read through what [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) lets you do, because 99% of these questions are answered by even just opening that URL and seeing the example of sorting an array using a sort function.

Comment: Before `sort` I would transform the list with `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 803, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-2", "course_id": 502, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 10, "time_taken": 296000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 0, "time_taken": 293000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 30, "time_taken": 287000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 504, "score": 20, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 504, "score": 10, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
]

const result = data.reduce((prev, elem)=>{
    if(prev[elem.user_id]){
        prev[elem.user_id] = {
            ...prev[elem.user_id], score: prev[elem.user_id].score + elem.score, time_taken: prev[elem.user_id].time_taken + elem.time_taken
        }
    }else{
  prev[elem.user_id] = elem
 }
return prev;

},{})

let ar = []

for(let key in result){
 ar.push(result[key])

}

const finalResult = ar.sort((a,b)=>b.score-a.score)
console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not just sorting, but potentially a sequence of `reduce`, `map` and then a `sort`:

```js
let data = [
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 802, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "8-a-1", "course_id": 803, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-2", "course_id": 502, "score": 10, "time_taken": 284000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 10, "time_taken": 296000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 0, "time_taken": 293000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 502, "score": 30, "time_taken": 287000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 504, "score": 20, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 504, "score": 10, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
    { "user_id": "5-a-1", "course_id": 503, "score": 0, "time_taken": 299000 },
];

let red=data.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
  let usr=acc[cur.user_id] || (acc[cur.user_id]={score:0,time:0});
  usr.score+=cur.score;
  usr.time+=cur.time_taken;
  return acc;
},{});
console.log("Reduced to an object with 3 keys");
console.log(red);
let result=Object.keys(red).map(key=>{
  let usr=red[key];
  return {
    user_id:key,
    score:usr.score,
    time:usr.time
  }
});
console.log("Mapped to an array");
console.log(result);
result.sort((a,b)=>a.user_id.localeCompare(b.user_id));
console.log("Sorted by user_id");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `lodash` since it can easily group-by and makes for more readable code. Using your `data` array:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const data = [...]; // As given in the question

// This will form a new row as the initial accumulator for reducing a group
function newRow(key) {
  return { user_id: key, score: 0, time_taken: 0 };
}

// reduce iterator that adds the values of a row to the accumulated values
function addRow(result, row, key) {
  return {
    ...result,
    score: result.score + row.score,
    time_taken: result.time_taken + row.time_taken,
  };
} 

// reduce a group of rows
function reduceRows(group, key) {
  return _.reduce(group, addRow, newRow(key));
}

// group the data by user_id
let res = _.groupBy(data, "user_id");

// convert into array, one entry per group
// each group gets reduced to a single row
res = _.map(res, reduceRows);

// since groupBy initially returns object that may not be sorted, sort it now
res = _.sortBy(res, "user_id");
```

See [REPL](https://repl.it/@RyanH1/groupsort)

Alternatively, using the FP version of lodash allows you to compose, if you're in to FP:

```
import _ from 'lodash/fp';

// Make map expose key, see: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1781
const map = _.map.convert({ 'cap': false });

const data = [...]; // As given in the question

const newRow = key => ({ user_id: key, score: 0, time_taken: 0 });

const addRow = (result, row, key) => ({
  ...result,
  score: result.score + row.score,
  time_taken: result.time_taken + row.time_taken,
}); 

const reduceRows = (group, key) => _.reduce(addRow, newRow(key), group);

const res = _.compose(
  _.sortBy("user_id"),
  map(reduceRows),
  _.groupBy("user_id"),
)(data);
```

See [REPL](https://repl.it/@RyanH1/groupsortfp)